# I am installing styled components in my React project but it gives me some errors

Tags: reactjs, eslintrc

[image]
This is the command i ran in the terminal but it gives me some errors related to ESLINT

Comment: try `npm i styled-components --force`

Comment: It seem like you have a dependency that does not work with other dependency on its current version.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Read more about the issue here: [relevant comment on Github issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2120#issuecomment-727533955)